# iCloud init on Sierra upgrade - did Apple "dox" me?

Tags: icloud, macos, privacy

I have files on my hard drive that I would rather not back up to the cloud.  I'm just fine using external disk drives the old fashioned way.

So when I upgraded to Sierra recently, it initialized iCloud as part of the new system init.  No opt-out choice which irritated me.  (**Edit**: When I unchecked the two boxes on the iCloud screen the Continue button became unclickable.  Apparently this is unique to me and not normal experience.)

As soon as I logged in to the new system I went straight to the iCloud config in system preferences to disable it.  When I disabled the backup drive it prompted me with choices what to do with all my files: never mind keep backup drive on, "keep local copy" and "delete on mac".  And "delete on mac" was the suggested / default!

Horrified, I chose to "keep local copy" and once that was done, frantically looked in all the folders I could think of to ensure that my files were still there.  It appears they are.

Now my question is, did I get "doxed" in this process?  Did the machine just start uploading all my files into Apple's cloud until I turned off iCloud backup drive?  (Or, dare I say, afterwards?)

Comment: These downvotes are just silly.  The question is so poor that it was answered clearly and the answer accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During Sierra setup assistant, a whole page is dedicated to whether you would like Documents and Desktop in iCloud Drive. You are specifically given a choice whether you would like to use this feature and can choose to not turn it on. As such I completely disagree that there was 'no opt-out'.

[image]

Since you enabled this feature, macOS will immediately begin uploading the contents of your Documents and Desktop folders to iCloud Drive. When you proceed to disable this, the Keep Local Copy option will ensure the documents remain on your computer. Delete on Mac is the default as that makes more sense for those who use this feature on purpose.

Doxing has a very specific meaning. Regardless of whether you meant to turn this feature on, your data were never published, therefore this cannot be doxing.

Comment: "macOS will immediately begin uploading the contents of your Documents and Desktop folders to iCloud Drive."  That's what I needed to know.  Thanks.  However, you missed one detail.  When I unchecked the boxes, the Continue button became unclickable!  Opt out indeed.

Comment: @wberry I’ve done well over 20 Sierra upgrades and unchecked both boxes every time, it’d make no sense to not let you continue! Perhaps you found a bug

Comment: Pure speculation, but I have an older model and this is now the fourth major OS version it's had.  I seem to remember this opt-out issue happening for at least the last two upgrades.  Perhaps it is an artifact of the machine's history somehow.  Good to know that it is not intended!

Comment: @wberry Documents and Desktop in iCloud Drive is a new feature in Sierra, you wouldn’t have been prompted for anything like that in earlier macOS; are you’re referring to a different feature?

Comment: Must be a different iCloud or maybe even Time Machine feature from previous releases that I'm thinking of.